# 802.11 Are the Frame Control Settings Set On the Access Point or the Client Device

Tags: ieee-802.11

I am currently reviewing this course
https://learningportal.juniper.net/juniper/user_activity_info.aspx?id=769

And it states you can set Frame Control Settings on Wireless networks such as: RTS threshold, Retry Counters, and Fragmentation threshold.

Is this set as a parameter to filter traffic on the client or the access device, or both?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This type of parameter can be set on both type of devices. The difference is that most of the time, if it is set on a station, it will only affect this particular station, while if it is set on the AP, it will affect every connected station.

However, certain parameters, like Greenfield, can be set on a station and will impact the whole network if the AP is set to allow it (Greenfield was a technology designed to improve speed on 802.11n networks, but it also prevents non-greenfield stations to listen to the traffic).